# Is it common or uncommon for someone to get the State Department’s Superior Honor Award three times?

Tags: united-states, state-department, awards

[According](https://web.archive.org/web/20190122041000/http://gothamwashington.com/stuart-seldowitz-foreign-affairs-chair/) to the biography of Stuart Seldowitz he

> is a three-time winner of the State Department’s Superior Honor Award.

I'm curious if that is unusual or a common occurrence. The Wikipedia [page on the award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_Honor_Award) doesn't shed much light on this: it lists a few recipients but none are said [there] to have gotten it multiple times.

So, is it common or uncommon for a career diplomat in the State Department to get that award multiple times? Or, [roughly] how many recipients of that award got it multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a full list of recipients but I have found some more people who got the Superior Honor Award multiple times:

[Julie Stufft](https://www.state.gov/biographies/julie-stufft/) has received is 7 times.

[Gabriel Escobar](https://www.state.gov/biographies/gabriel-escobar/) 6 times.

[David Schlaefer](https://2017-2021.state.gov/biographies/david-a-schlaefer/) 5 times.

Several other people have received it multiple times according to their biographies on the state.gov website. I found them with a Google Search of "superior honor award site:state.gov".

All in all, receiving multiple Superior Honor Awards does not appear to be unprecendented, while still being rare and limited to people with an illustrious career in US foreign policy.